# BoxWhiskerChart features breaking with massive WeightedData datasets

Tags: plotting, dataset, charts

I have huge WeightedData objects (500K) that I am trying to plot in BoxWhiskerChart.  I can get the default chart, but if I try and use the "Outliers" option, it breaks and hits a recursion limit.

Sample Code based on documentation section "Basic Examples":
create 8 weighted datasets:

```
random500Klist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], {8, 500000}];  
randomWeightedData = WeightedData[#, #^2] & /@ random500Klist;
```

Make box and whisker chart:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[randomWeightedData, {"Outliers", {"Outliers", 
   "\[FilledCircle]"}, {"FarOutliers", "\[EmptyCircle]"}}, 
 ChartStyle -> 56]
```

Error outputs:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of AugmentedData`ValidAugmentedDataQ[WeightedData[]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of WeightedData[].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of AugmentedData`ValidAugmentedDataQ[WeightedData[]].

General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Any way to resolve?

Comment: I tried increasing $RecursionLimit to 1 billion but my kernel crashed.  i will try again tmmrw.

Comment: It occurs with much less data too in 12.1.1, for example: `SeedRandom[0]; random500Klist = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {2, 20}];` and running the simpler `BoxWhiskerChart[randomWeightedData, "Outliers"]`. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Wolfram has confirmed it is a bug